# nginx proxying and custom business logic

Tags: nginx, proxy

I need to proxy all user request from user to domain A -> to external domain B.

Also I need to introduce some custom business logic while proxying from A to B.

One of the task for this custom business logic - I need to process HTML on the fly and replace in HTML all links from domain B to A. Also, I need to proxy HTTP cookies and I need to implement content targeting based on different conditions.

Is it possible with nginx ? Is so, what languages can be used for custom business logic writing ? I'm a Java developer so I'm primarily interested in this language but also looking for a most efficient way.

If no, could you please suggest more suitable alternatives for this task.

Comment: Really interested in finding an answer to this - were you successful in your search?